# Run process with realtime output in PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, process, real-time

I am trying to run a process on a web page that will return its output in realtime. For example if I run 'ping' process it should update my page every time it returns a new line (right now, when I use exec(command, output) I am forced to use -c option and wait until process finishes to see the output on my web page). Is it possible to do this in php?

I am also wondering what is a correct way to kill this kind of process when someone is leaving the page. In case of 'ping' process I am still able to see the process running in the system monitor (what makes sense).

Comment: Nginx X-Accel buffering can prevent the accepted answer from working, to make it work, add this header before:
```
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

Comment: for me Nginx buffering was the issue above comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$cmd = "ping 127.0.0.1";

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
echo "<pre>";
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;
        flush();
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: This doesn't doing anything for me, on Fedora php 5+

Comment: +1 works for me, but only if I add `ob_implicit_flush(true);ob_end_flush();` at the beginning

Comment: Combine this with Robb's answer and you have a goer.

Comment: I wrapped this in a function so I could call it just like `shell_exec`. Works nicely if you just want to show the output and not do any processing on it.

Comment: Good example is on `proc_open()` [PHP manual page](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#refsect1-function.proc-open-examples)

Comment: ..and in [PHPCI project source code](https://github.com/Block8/PHPCI/blob/92ee90998a1b6b218656195a78366542d74a97a3/PHPCI/Helper/BaseCommandExecutor.php#L85-L109)

Comment: If calling calling a Python script, use `-u` so it does not buffer output.

Comment: If using Apache and PHP-FPM in Proxy mode, you might need `<Proxy "fcgi://localhost">ProxySet flushpackets=on</Proxy>`

Answer (score 39):

This is a nice way to show real time output of your shell commands:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");

// tell php to automatically flush after every output
// including lines of output produced by shell commands
disable_ob();

$command = 'rsync -avz /your/directory1 /your/directory2';
system($command);
```

You will need this function to prevent output buffering:

```
function disable_ob() {
    // Turn off output buffering
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
    // Turn off PHP output compression
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
    // Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
    ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    // Clear, and turn off output buffering
    while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
        // Get the curent level
        $level = ob_get_level();
        // End the buffering
        ob_end_clean();
        // If the current level has not changed, abort
        if (ob_get_level() == $level) break;
    }
    // Disable apache output buffering/compression
    if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
        apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
        apache_setenv('dont-vary', '1');
    }
}
```

It doesn't work on every server I have tried it on though, I wish I could offer advice on what to look for in your php configuration to determine whether or not you should pull your hair out trying to get this type of behavior to work on your server!  Anyone else know?

Here's a dummy example in plain PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");

disable_ob();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) 
{
    echo $i . "\n";
    usleep(300000);
}
```

I hope this helps others who have googled their way here.

Comment: This doesn't work with ````exec()````. ````system()```` works fine though.

Comment: This worked really well for me, It doesn't update constantly but every so often. Its better then nothing. Thank you.

Comment: this produced the desired effect for me on CentOS 6.5 / apache 2.2 / php 5.3. cheers!

Comment: This works great for me (OS X 10.12, Apache 2.2.3, PHP 7.0.9), but for some reason only when the X-Content-Type-Options header is also set: `header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');`

Comment: Since the browsers usually wait for some initial pack of data, you can send a lot of whitespace at the beginning, so that the initial buffer is filled: `for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    echo " "; }
echo "\n";
flush();`

Comment: For me, `passthru` works better than `system` (for showing the output of `rsync --progress`).

Comment: This worked for me on one machine, but for my other server I get this error:"Warning: ini_set(): Cannot change zlib.output_compression - headers already sent in /var/www/html/index.php on line 16" , its pointing to this line: "ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);"Any help?

Answer (score 13):

Checked all answers, nothing works...

Found solution [Here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=579738)

It works on windows (i think this answer is helpful for users searching over there)

```
<?php
    $a = popen('ping www.google.com', 'r'); 
    
    while($b = fgets($a, 2048)) { 
        echo $b."<br>\n"; 
        ob_flush();flush(); 
    }

    pclose($a); 
?>
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me when I had to run a python script. Others didn't work as well.

Answer (score 7):

A better solution to this old problem using modern HTML5 Server Side Events is described here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

---

**Example:**

http://sink.agiletoolkit.org/realtime/console

Code: https://github.com/atk4/sink/blob/master/admin/page/realtime/console.php#L40

(Implemented as a module in Agile Toolkit framework)

Comment: IE/Edge does not support this... ;)

Answer (score 6):

For command-line usage:

```
function execute($cmd) {
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, [['pipe','r'],['pipe','w'],['pipe','w']], $pipes);
    while(($line = fgets($pipes[1])) !== false) {
        fwrite(STDOUT,$line);
    }
    while(($line = fgets($pipes[2])) !== false) {
        fwrite(STDERR,$line);
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    return proc_close($proc);
}
```

If you're trying to run a file, you may need to give it execute permissions first:

```
chmod('/path/to/script',0755);
```

Answer (score 5):

try this (tested on Windows machine + wamp server)

```
        header('Content-Encoding: none;');

        set_time_limit(0);

        $handle = popen("<<< Your Shell Command >>>", "r");

        if (ob_get_level() == 0) 
            ob_start();

        while(!feof($handle)) {

            $buffer = fgets($handle);
            $buffer = trim(htmlspecialchars($buffer));

            echo $buffer . "<br />";
            echo str_pad('', 4096);    

            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
        }

        pclose($handle);
        ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question was how to get page output in realtime. With ob_start() you do just the opposite: You write all output to an internal server buffer instead of sending it immediately to the browser!

Comment: i have tried ur code,,actually its not displaying shell command in real time, but just wait shell command to finish load all text and displaying it bit by bit using sleep(1) help. sorry, u deserve downvote

Answer (score 5):

I've tried various PHP execution commands on Windows and found that they differ quite a lot.

- Don't work for streaming: `shell_exec`, `exec`, `passthru`
- Kind of works: `proc_open`, `popen` -- "kind of" because you cannot pass arguments to your command (i.e. wont' work with `my.exe --something`, will work with `_my_something.bat`).

The best (easiest) approach is:

1. You must make sure your exe is flushing commands (see [printf flushing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)). Without this you will most likely receive batches of about 4096 bytes of text whatever you do.
2. If you can, use `header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');` (instead of `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=...');`). This will not work in all browsers/clients though! Streaming will work without this, but at least first lines will be buffered by the browser.
3. You also might want to disable cache `header('Cache-Control: no-cache');`.
4. Turn off output buffering (either in php.ini or with `ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');`). This might also have to be done in Apache/Nginx/whatever server you use in front.
5. Turn of compression (either in php.ini or with `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);`). This might also have to be done in Apache/Nginx/whatever server you use in front.

So in your C++ program you do something like (again, for other solutions see [printf flushing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)):

```
Logger::log(...) {
  printf (text);
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

In PHP you do something like:

```
function setupStreaming() {
    // Turn off output buffering
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
    // Turn off PHP output compression
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
    // Disable Apache output buffering/compression
    if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
        apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
        apache_setenv('dont-vary', '1');
    }
}
function runStreamingCommand($cmd){
    echo "\nrunning $cmd\n";
    system($cmd);
}
...

setupStreaming();
runStreamingCommand($cmd);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to run system commands via PHP look into, [the exec documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).

I wouldn't recommend doing this on a high traffic site though, forking a process for each request is quite a hefty process. Some programs provide the option of writing their process id to a file such that you could check for, and terminate the process at will, but for commands like ping, I'm not sure that's possible, check the man pages.

You may be better served by simply opening a socket on the port you expect to be listening (IE: port 80 for HTTP) on the remote host, that way you know everything is going well in userland, as well as on the network.

If you're attempting to output binary data look into [php's header function](http://php.net/header), and ensure you set the proper [content-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-type), and [content-disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt). Review [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), for more information on using/disabling the output buffer.

Answer (score 3):

First check whether [flush()](http://cn.php.net/flush) works for you. If it does, good, if it doesn't it probably means the web server is buffering for some reason, for example mod_gzip is enabled.

For something like ping, the easiest technique is to loop within PHP, running "ping -c 1" multiple times, and calling flush() after each output. Assuming PHP is configured to abort when the HTTP connection is closed by the user (which is usually the default, or you can call ignore_user_abort(false) to make sure), then you don't need to worry about run-away ping processes either.

If it's really necessary that you only run the child process *once* and display its output continuously, that may be more difficult -- you'd probably have to run it in the background, redirect output to a stream, and then have PHP echo that stream back to the user, interspersed with regular flush() calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the php.ini file set "output_buffering = Off". You should be able to get the real time output on the page 
Use system command instead of exec.. system command will flush the output

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem only could do it using Symfony Process Components ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html )

Quick example:

```
<?php 

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['ls', '-lsa']);
$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
    }
});

?>
```

Comment: This makes things so easy. 10/10

Answer (score 0):

why not just pipe the output into a log file and then use that file to return content to the client. not quite real time but perhaps good enough?