# PHP and bash scripting

Tags: php, bash, logfiles

I am using php to install some binaries. I call bash script in my php pages for this purpose. But it takes long to install these binaries. Is there anyway to log the progress of this execution or is there any way to present the process taking place on the screen (php web page)?

Comment: if the php pages in which you are using to install 'binaries' don't have a logging feature, then you can't see it.

Comment: is there any output in your bash during installation ?

Comment: @ Shivan - I get the whole bash output on my next php page like reading dependency table ....installing.....

Comment: here's the answer on realtime output, worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5956708/1418546

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run process with realtime output in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281140/run-process-with-realtime-output-in-php)