# Bash output in web browser

Tags: php, bash

I made a script in bash for getting pings into a file.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting script"
echo "Working.."
while true; do
    DATE=$(date)
    PING=$(ping -c 1 google.pl | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2)
    echo "$DATE Ping: $PING" >> logs/ping.txt
    sleep 5000
done
```

But due to lack of free space i changed `echo "$DATE Ping: $PING" >> logs/ping.txt` to just `echo "$DATE Ping: $PING"` to recive every line in cmd, and it worked [image]

But still the main idea is to run the scipt through the web browser and display its output. (i can run it tho but i have no idea how to show echo output in a browser)

Comment: You tagged this as PHP; What do you have so far?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Other *.sh scripts which i am using have normal php code inside so i thought that there is a way to do that in php too.

Comment: Just like I said i would like to see output of this script in web browser not just in console.

Comment: do you have a web server set up for php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the bash script from php using:

```
exec('myscript.sh');
```

And then open the ping.txt using:

```
$myFile = "ping.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```

Without text file:

```
$ping = shell_exec('myscript.sh');
echo "<pre>$ping</pre>";
```

Comment: Yup its good option but like I said i cant use script version with ping.txt due to lack of space, it must be something like echo in cmd but in web browser

Comment: Output will be shown only when script will stop and I need realtime preview

Comment: Have a look at that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281140/run-process-with-realtime-output-in-php

Comment: Does `$ping` contain the stdout as string? That means that shell_exec is synchronous, right?

Comment: @Nenotlep Yes, it's a string. I'm not a PHP expert but I believe the shell_exec is synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of ajax and using  [Net_Ping](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Ping/docs) you could have a page that updates in near-realtime.
Alternatively use shell_exec to run ping from inside your php and echo the output returned from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute your bash script from PHP and display the output in a browser, then just use the `shell_exec()` PHP function

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/path/script-name-here');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Output will be shown only when script will stop and I need realtime preview

Comment: Typically a webserver will always server the content from start to finish. It isnt really designed to keep a connection open and keep sending your information.

So, along the lines of what kguest wrote; you will need to make multiple asynchronous requests with javascript, and display the results in the browser as each response comes back in.