# using PHP shell_exec so that the output is "piped" not "dumped"

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec, command-line-interface, passthru

quick question really.

Consider the following code:

```
//__/var/test/cli_test.php__
$x = 0;
while ($x < 9){
  print "loop " . str_pad($x, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
  sleep(1);
  $x++;
}
```

if I type `php /var/test/cli_test.php` in the command line I get 9 interspaced-by-time lines.. i.e. 9 positive outputs, one per second. EG: these arrive one at a time, blip blip blip...

```
loop 000 
loop 001 
loop 002 
loop 003 
loop 004 
loop 005 
loop 006 
loop 007 
loop 008
```

now consider a different proposition

```
//__/var/test/cli_test_shell.php
print shell_exec("php /var/test/cli_test.php");
```

if I type `php /var/test/cli_test_shell.php` in the command line I get nothing for 9 seconds then everything arrives.. i.e. 1 BIG output 1 BIG wait. after 9 seconds of nothing EG: wait, wait wait.. nothing THEN DUMP:

```
loop 000 
loop 001 
loop 002 
loop 003 
loop 004 
loop 005 
loop 006 
loop 007 
loop 008
```

how can I alter `/var/test/cli_test_shell.php` so that the output returns each line on per second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$handle = popen('php /var/test/cli_test_shell.php 2>&1', 'r');
while (!feof($handle)) {
  echo fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I fixed it with this `disable_ob()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281140/run-process-with-realtime-output-in-php

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

The desired behaviour is not possible using `shell_exec()`. This is because the function collects the output of the command and returns it as a string - after the command's termination. Use [`passthru()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead and keep `cli_test.php` as it is.

Comment: thanks :) but you have mis-read, the question was  "how can I alter /var/test/cli_test_shell.php" .. you may notice I already "tagged" passthru(), I am not convinced it will function correctly that way without ob_flush's() you see

Comment: how should it work with shell_exec()? `print` will being executed after `shell_exec()` returns.

Comment: `shell_exec` / `exec` / `passthru` it's all one of the same problem, the question is how do I alter it to get 9 piped lines "live", my best guess is that it is a `exec` with a ob_flush call back on the $output but I don't know ho to achieve it elegantly

Comment: ... if you want to have both immediate output and the output in a variable you can use popen() or proc_open(). you have full control over the pipes then