# Output in command line is not showing

Tags: php, command-line

I have these lines in PHP:

```
public function run(){
    $command = 'php -S localhost:1337';
    exec($command);
}
```

I created a simple commands in php, something like this:

```
php file run
```

When the user enters this command, PHP goes to the method run() but the output message is empty and the server already are running.

But when I run the `command php -S localhost:8000` directly in cli it shows this message:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\hola>php -S localhost:8000
PHP 5.6.31 Development Server started at Mon Jan 15 15:52:34 2018
Listening on http://localhost:8000
```

Why the output message of the command line is not showing only when the command is executed from a file?.

Comment: `system($command);`

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` function's signature is:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

So if you do something like the following, it should work:

```
public function run(){
    $output = array();
    $command = 'php -S localhost:1337';
    exec($command, $output);
    echo implode("\n", $output);
}
```

After the `exec` function completes, the output will be in `$output` with each output line as an element of the array. The `implode` function will then combine the elements of the array into a string separated by a newline, and then the `echo` statement will print this string.

Comment: it still does not work, i have another methods, that the user can call from cli, but run() is the only one that doesnt work, 
it's like I execute the exec, and it would stop there, because I do an echo commenting all the lines and there's a text output.

Comment: So you tried something like `echo implode("\n", $output);` after the `exec` line and it didn't show you any output?

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned the `shell_exec` function yet. Combine @pgngp and @DrKey's answers for this:

```
public function run(){
    $command = 'php -S localhost:1337';
    echo shell_exec($command);
}
```

The difference here is that `exec` only returns the last line of output where `shell_exec` returns the entire result of the command executed. Additionally, the backtic (`` `ls -al` ``) operator is the same as running `shell_exec`.

```
public function run(){
    echo `php -S localhost:1337`;
}
```

Comment: doesnt works too :C why? if i add an echo at the first line of the method something like this echo "hello". in the cli only shows "hello" and it stops there, i mean the command is succesfully executed but the output doesnt shows

Comment: So the server does start? Are you just trying to use this as a shortcut for starting the development server? I'm not able to call a function defined in the php file from the command line. 

I'd recommend adding a `#!/usr/bin/env php` shebang to the top of the file, `chmod +x` and moving ``echo `php -S localhost:1337`;`` outside a method. You're not doing anything to parse `$argv` (which will be defined when calling from the command line).

Comment: Try calling `run();` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

`exec` doesn't returns output in realtime, just at command execution end, but `php -S` is never ends. I suppose you are looking for something like [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).
Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6144213/8117560) helps you